# Protein interaction dataset and MLN script explanation

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

I have a protein interaction dataset. In that function(p1,+f1) v !function(p1,+f2) is a rule in its MLN script. What does + mean in this?

Comment: I don't know what an MLN script is, but if it's a dynamically typed language it's possible that the unary + could be used to ensure that a variable is treated as a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, let me make simpler version of the problem. Let there be a formula with only one predicate `P(a,b)`. Here, `a` and `b` takes value from domain `A` and `B`, respectively.

Now, if you want to learn weight for `P(a,b_i)` foe each `b_i in B`, then instead for writing `|B|` (cardinality of `B`) number of formulas, you can write in compact form `P(a,+b)`.

In your case, let's assume that `function` is name of some predicate, and second argument comes from some domain `F` with cardinality `|F|`.
Then, this formula will be expanded `|F|^2` times and weight for each of new formula will be learned by MLN tool.